# How to use Linksys X2000 as repeater

Tags: wireless-networking, repeater, wireless-extender

I've 4G mini-router [Huawei E5776s-32](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81oprubs4YL._SL1500_.jpg) and [Linksys X2000](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/electronics/detail-page/linksys/sm-B005HFJFHW.SIDE.jpg) router in my home, my 4G router can cover some spots in home I want to user Linksys router to extend 4G router.

I tried [these steps](http://www.ehow.com/how_6848173_set-linksys-router-wireless-repeater.html) and I wifi signal extended but when a machine connect to extended wifi signal it'll be disconnected from the internet.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps and mine did the same thing. But then realised that you have to have the ethernet port plugged into one of the three 'ethernet' ports, not the 'cable' port at the back.